# How send data(extra) from a map activity To an other activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I am new to programming and i want to know how to send data (dual coordinates) from my map activity to another activity. I tried the conventional method but it only works when I send data from the activity to another activity and not from my fragmentmaps activity to another activity.

Comment: share your code and then explain whats problem you facing.

Comment: It's literally the same thing: you send data from activity to activity via `Intents` and their associated `Bundle`s

Comment: like Thunder already said: share a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map fragment is implemented in the activity only. So, normal activity intent will work here.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourMapActivity.this, NextActiity.class);
intent.putExtra("Latitude", latitude);
intent.putExtra("Longitude", longitude);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks my problem that i receive a null vallue